What kind of arrays can be considered as Null array in Powershell or how to declare a Null array?
I defined an array as below:
$array =@($null)

On comparing this array with $null the output suggests it's not null
if($null -eq $array)
    {
     'Array is $null'
    }

--> Doesn't return any value
Isn't this a null array? If not, why?



@($null)

This is a single-element array whose (one and only) element is $null
By contrast, @() creates an empty array (an array object without elements), and $null in isolation is just that: a value indicating the absence of an object.
To initialize an array to $null, you can use [array] $array = $null, with [array] serving as a type constraint, though the only benefit this brings over $array = $null (i.e., creating a variable that can accept any type) is that if you later assign a value that isn't an array, it will be coerced to one (e.g., assigning $array = 42 later is in effect the same as $array = @(42)).

Comparing a value to $null (with it on the LHS)[1] with -eq only ever succeeds if the RHS is $null too (or its quasi-equivalent, the enumerable null, which is technically the [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value singleton, which is output behind the scenes from commands that produce no output).[2]
Thus, $null -eq @($null) is $false, for instance.

Testing if an array is null or empty is best done via its .Count property:
if ($array.Count -eq 0) { # ...

Perhaps surprisingly, this also works with $null, thanks to the intrinsic .Count property that PowerShell exposes on any object that doesn't natively have it, as well as on $null ($null.Count yields 0).
While use of if (-not $array) { # ... , i.e. implicit to-Boolean conversion, is tempting, it can yield false positives, given that a single-element array (enumerable) is treated like its one and only element.
Notably, your @($null) example demonstrates this problem:
# !! -> 'EMPTY', even though the array is NOT empty.
if (-not @($null)) { 'EMPTY' }


[1] With $null as the RHS, when combined with an array-valued (enumerable) LHS, it acts as a filter, returning the sub-array of elements that are $null - this behavior is shared by all comparison operators - see the docs
[2] For background information, see the "Enumerable Null" section of the "Everything you wanted to know about $null" help topic.

A declared array is never null for PowerShell, however when coerced to boolean they're false if empty:
$array = @()
$null -eq $array  # false
$array -as [bool] # false

So checking if an array is empty can become:
if(-not $array) {
    'Array is $null or empty'
}

This behavior is clarified in the about Booleans documentation in the Converting from collection types section:

Arrays are the most common collection type in PowerShell. These rules apply to any collection-like types that implement the IList interface.

Empty collections are always $false
The special null value indicating the absence of output from a command, [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value is always $false.
Single-element collections evaluate to the Boolean value of their one and only element.
Collections with more than 1 element are always $true.


For details on AutomationNull see Enumerable null.
